# How to get first and last read within a range specified in temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, one containing a date range and a node key, another containing a group of all the readings in the system associated to each node. I'm trying to find the most efficient way to find the closest readings (first and last) for each node that fall within the range specified within the first table.

The Reading Table Consists of the following:

```
                   NodeID,Endtime,DataValue
```

The other table contains:

```
                   EndpointID, NodeID, startDate, endDate
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
                   EndpointId,
                   Node ID, 
                   Reading closest to and >= start date,
                   Reading closest to and <= end date
```

The script below does what I want but is not the most efficient and because the reading table is massive this times out even on a small number of nodes.

```
SELECT  t.EndpointID,
    t.SPCNodeID,
    b.FirstRead as First_Read_DateTime,
    c.LastRead as Last_Read_DateTime

FROM    #Temp1 t
LEFT JOIN (               
  Select t1.EndpointID,
         MIN(R.EndTime) FirstRead
 From Reading R,
      #Temp1 t1
 Where      t1.SPCNodeID = R.NodeID
 AND        R.EndTime >= t1.First_Date_In_Range  
 AND        R.EndTime <= t1.Last_Date_In_Range  
 Group By t1.EndpointID      
) as b
on  t.EndpointID = b.EndpointID     

LEFT JOIN (  
 Select t1.EndpointID,
        MAX(R.EndTime) LastRead
 From Reading R,
      #Temp1 t1
 Where      t1.SPCNodeID = R.NodeID
 AND        R.EndTime >= t1.First_Date_In_Range  
 AND        R.EndTime <= t1.Last_Date_In_Range  
 Group By t1.EndpointID  
 ) as c
 on  t.EndpointID = c.EndpointID    

 ORDER BY t.EndpointID, Last_Date_In_Range DESC
```

I have a feeling there is a better way to do this that will be more efficient but I'm having trouble coming up with it.

Comment: when you say _closest readings (first and last) for each node that fall within the range specified_, do you mean the earliest reading on or after the startDate and latest reading on or before the enddate?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?:

```
SELECT  t.EndpointID,
    t.SPCNodeID,
    First_Read_DateTime,
    Last_Read_DateTime
FROM #Temp1 as t
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX(R.EndTime) as Last_Read_DateTime FROM Reading as r 
    WHERE t.SPCNodeID = R.NodeID and R.EndTime <= t.Last_Date_In_Range
) as rmax
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MIN(R.EndTime) as Last_Read_DateTime FROM Reading as r 
    WHERE t.SPCNodeID = R.NodeID and R.EndTime >= t.First_Date_In_Range
) as rmin
```

Not guarantee its working, just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need two left outer joins, you can determine the MIN() and MAX() values (if any) in the same subquery:

```
SELECT  
    t.EndpointID,
    t.SPCNodeID,
    FirstRead as First_Read_DateTime,
    LastRead as Last_Read_DateTime
FROM    
    #Temp1 t    LEFT JOIN 
    (Select t1.EndpointID,
         MIN(R.EndTime) FirstRead,
         MAX(R.EndTime) LastRead
     From 
        Reading R inner join      
        #Temp1 t1    on 
          t1.SPCNodeID = R.NodeID   AND        
          R.EndTime >= t1.First_Date_In_Range AND        
          R.EndTime <= t1.Last_Date_In_Range  
     Group By t1.EndpointID) as b on  
    t.EndpointID = b.EndpointID 
ORDER BY t.EndpointID, Last_Date_In_Range DESC
```